# How to change load layout in Joomla view?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

By default  `parent::display($tpl);` loads `components/com_my_component/views/my_component/tmpl/default.php`, but in some cases i need to load other php file which is in the same folder near `default.php` (for example `components/com_my_component/views/my_component/tmpl/lol.php`). How to do this from `view.html.php`.

P.S.

Tried load `loadTemplate` and `setLayout` methods with no luck.

Comment: I think it's layout=lol.

Comment: could you please paste the full url that you are passing?

Comment: @Irfan localhost ))) But problem already solved

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved the problem by myself. Need to use the method [setLayout](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Layout.FileLayout.html#method_setLayout) and pay attention to the input syntax

```
$this->setLayout('dafault:lol');
parent::display($tpl);
```

Comment: I get an error in the controller Fatal error: Call to undefined method FcseController::setLayout() in /var/www/pygmaxia2.gr/components/com_fcse/controller.php on line 33 and the code in the line is this $this->setLayout('dafault:test');
Any Idea?

Comment: oh I did $view= new JView();  
  $view->setLayout('dafault:test'); and it worked :)

Comment: This code will cause joomla to ignore the `layout` request parameter. Please see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31833510/1031312

Answer (score 3):

By default, joomla looks for the `layout` keyword in the URL to decide which layout to display. If this variable is empty or not present then the `tmpl/default.php` layout will be loaded.

By editting your `view.html.php` file you can set the default layout by using the JView API, e.g. [`$this->setLayout('lol')`](https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JView::setLayout) will make the URL `example.com/yourview` equivalent to `example.com/yourview?layout=lol`.

However, **this change alone will result in Joomla overriding it's default behaviour** so that the `layout` request will be ignored. This means that the request `example.com/yourview?layout=lmao` will also display `example.com/yourview` = `example.com/yourview?layout=lol`

You can solve this easily by adding a condition around the `setLayout` function so that only if the `layout` keyword is not present then you will set the default layout to `lol`, e.g.

> ```
>     <?php 
>     # ...
>
>       function display($tpl = null) {
>         # ...
>
>         # Edit : Set the default layout to 'lol'
>         $layout = JRequest::getWord('layout', '');
>         if (empty($layout)) $this->setLayout("lol");
>
>         // Display the view
>         parent::display($tpl);
>       }
>
>     # ...
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I keep coming back to this and I've yet to find a satisfying solution.

What does work, from J1.5 right up to J3.4, for me has always been to set the $tpl variable in view.html.php

If $tpl is empty or "" then tmpl/default.php is displayed by default.

If you change $tpl to a string, e.g. $tpl="stacker" then it will look for and display tmpl/default_stacker.php

I've seen various differing theories on changing it earlier in the MVC so that it doesn't need the default_ pretext. e.g. tmpl/stacker.php
None have worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, Totally overlooked the `$tpl` variable.